# How to add rows to a matrix with pad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a matrix like this:

```
profile=np.array([[0,0,0.5,0.1],
                  [0.3,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0.1,0.9],
                  [0,0,0,0.1],
                  [0,0.5,0,0]])
```

And I want to add a row before and after filled with zeros. How can I do that?
I thought of using `np.pad` but not sure how.

Output should be:

```
np.array([[0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0.5,0.1],
          [0.3,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0.1,0.9],
          [0,0,0,0.1],
          [0,0.5,0,0]
          [0,0,0,0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `np.pad` function allows you to specify the axes you want to pad:

```py
In [3]: np.pad(profile, ((1, 1), (0, 0)))
Out[3]:
array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.5, 0.1],
       [0.3, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.9],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.1],
       [0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

The nested tuple can be read as: pad 1 array "above", and 1 array "below" axis 0, and pad 0 arrays "above" and 0 arrays "below" axis 1.

Another example, which pads five columns "after" on axis 1:

```py
In [4]: np.pad(profile, ((0, 0), (0, 5)))
Out[4]:
array([[0. , 0. , 0.5, 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.3, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.9, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.pad`:

```
out = np.pad(profile, 1)[:, 1:-1]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.5, 0.1],
       [0.3, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.9],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.1],
       [0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Because `np.pad` pads it on *all sides* (left and right, in addition to top and bottom), `[:, 1:-1]` slices off the first and last columns.

Comment: While this works, it could end up being pretty memory-intensive if you need to pad a large number of values. Better to [use an array-like / sequence](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) for the `pad_width` parameter.

Comment: Ah, I see your solution. Nice one! I'll keep that in mind :)